# SQL - two tables retrieving data

Tags: php, mysql

i try to retrieve data but i think i'm not good at sql query.

i have a table eventCategory
[image]

and one more table
[image]

This two table is created in order to use in one table
this is the initplayer table. 
What i want to do retrieve data like that

30191592 Izlesene.com 7 2012-02-22 izlesene_cihan_v4

How can i do that ? pls show me the way ? How can i use these two tables?

[image]

Comment: would u better write your table name and parent child reference between keys

Comment: You should have a relations table for these two tables or a column in existing tables which would help to set relations between that two tables. After that you can use `JOIN` in your query to bind the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
SELECT la.id,st.profileName, la.totalEvents,la.Date,ft.eventCategory
FROM lastTable la
INNER JOIN secondTable st ON st.id=la.id
INNER JOIN firstTable ft ON ft.id = la.eventCategoryID
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say the name of the second table so I will just call it T2.

```
select * 
from   T2 join 
       eventCategory AS e on T2.eventCategoryID = e.id
```

I'm assuming your second table has an 'eventCategoryID' field.  If it doesn't, then I would need to know how you would relate it to the other table.